# Non-Unitarily Diagonalizable Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory

When searching for matrices that are similar to a diagonal matrix but not in a unitary way then a first hint would be to exclude the normal ones. But apart from that is there a general form for such matrices as the Jordan decomposition for nondiagonalizable matrices?

Comment: Any matrix is similar to its Jordan Canonical form. The matrices implementing the "similarity" need not be unitary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any matrix is similar to its Jordan Canonical form. The matrices implementing the "similarity" need not be unitary.